# What is the "best practice" on taking down a helicopter with a (single) Stinger?

Tags: battlefield-3

This is how I usually try to take down a helicopter:

- If he is too far away, I usually don't even care (longer "lock-on" time, reload countermeasures, etc.)

  - if he is mid to close range I usually lock-on, fire, he countermeasures
  - then I fire the second shot and usually this gives me the "vehicle disabled" message

But I'm curious how you do this and if there is a more "efficient" way. For example lock-on, wait till he countermeasures, wait a bit, then fire?

Comment: I'd make sure my team mates distract him first. BTW, is it for the single player campaign, or multiplayer? We have tags for both, [tag:single-player] and [tag:multiplayer] respectively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Works only on some pilots, but here is the method I use:

Firstly, I get a lock onto him and wait for him to *lose his nerves* and fire a salvo of IR-flares.

Then I fire my first missile, and immediately after that the second, if he is still in sight and range.

This will consequently fail on experienced pilots, since their first reaction is to fly far away if they can, and if not, they wait for the threat missile launch, and then release the countermeasures.

Comment: To add to this: If you're close enough to the chopper, then you can fire your stinger before they use their flares and they either won't have enough time to deploy flares, or even if they do, the stinger is too close to miss them.

Comment: I just had the most annoying chopper pilot. 1500 tickets map, didn't die once. Just flew low to avoid tracking and lock-on, if it worked, took forever because of his chopper upgrades (at least it felt like it) - though I was probably the only one shooting at him

Comment: This is by far the easiest approach to taking down air vehicles, as soon as the pilots hear the lock on tone they pop flares.

Comment: Do you fire it immediately after he fired the IR-flares (because that causes the missile to still follow the flares, at least sometimes) or do you wait a few seconds?

Comment: good catch! I wait for the flares dissipate a bit, then fire.

Answer (score 0):

My answer would be to either fire only when they are too close for countermeasures to be effective or use a non targeting anti-armour solution (RPG, SMAW) while this may not be easier they cannot be redirected by countermeasures. I like Bora's idea however it is very inconsistent and I wouldn't rely on it.

Hope this helps.